# Ansible: Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather than running sudo

Tags: ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

When I run this:

`ansible host -u myuser -a "sudo su - otheruser -s /bin/bash"`

I get warning:

```
[WARNING]: Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather
than running sudo

host | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
```

But what would be equivalent using `become` for `sudo su - otheruser -s /bin/bash`?

I tried:

```
ansible host -u myuser --become --become-user otheruser -a "/bin/echo hello"
```

But I get:

```
host | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to host closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
    "rc": 1
}
```

P.S. Ansible version: 2.6.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to specify `--become_method su`. Or more specifically `ansible host -u myuser --become-method su --become-user otheruser -a "/bin/echo hello"`

P.S. I'm passing `-a "/bin/echo hello"`, because ansible expect to run some command after changing user.